# Reverse relation in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to fetch multiple images for a particular post-id and i have a piece of code which is working for me but I am not able to understand why/how?
If anyone can explain and/or give me some documentation for the same I would be able to use it in future as well.
This is the code I am trying to understand.

Thanks.

```
 {% for posts in posts %}
   {{ posts.id }}  
   {% for image in posts.post.all %}<!--first post is for the "for loop" second post for the post field in model and all is for all images I guess.-->
   {{ image.image }}
   <a href='#'><img src='{{ image.image.url }}' class="img img-responsive image " width='100'/> </a><br>
   {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
```

view.html:

```
   *{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block main_content %}

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        {% if posts %}
    {% for post in posts %}
    </div>
    <div class="strip">
        <div class="row">

        <div class='col-md-8'>
         <h6><a href="/final/{{ post.id }}" class="nav-link js-create-book" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">{{ post.title|title }}</a></h6>
         </div>
          <div class='col-md-4'>
         <a  href="/delete/{{ post.id }}" class='demo'><i class="fa fa-close pull-right"></i></a>
        <a  href="/edit/{{ post.id }}" class='' ><i class="fa fa-pencil pull-right"></i></a>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
         <div class="col-md-10">
             <div class="descrip">
         <p><small>{{ post.description|truncatechars:250 }}</small>
        </p>

</div><!-- descrip ends-->
<p><small><strong>{{ post.created_at }}</strong></small></p>
<!-- <p><small><strong>{{ dog.updated_at }}</strong></small></p> -->
</div><!-- col-md-9 ends-->

<div class="col-md-2 center">

   {% for posts in posts %}
   {{ posts.id }}  
   {% for image in posts.post.all %}<!--first post is for the "for loop" second post for the post field in model and all is for all images I guess.-->
   {{ image.image }}
   <a href='#'><img src='{{ image.image.url }}' class="img img-responsive image " width='100'/> </a><br>
   {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}


</div>


      <div class='img-modal'>
       <a class='image' href='#'>
       <div class='title'>
       <i class='fa fa-close'></i>
     </div></a>
            <img src='{{ image.image.url }}' class="img img-responsive change"/> 
                <a href="/delete-image/{{ image.id }}" class='demo'>Delete</a><br/>     
</div>

     </div><!-- strip ends-->
 {% endfor %}

 {% else %}
<h3 class='error'>No Entry yet!!Please add entry.</h3>

{% endif %}
</div>
 {% endblock %}*
```

views.py:

```
def view(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated(): #or request.session.get_expiry_age()> 10):
    request.session.set_expiry(600000)
    user = request.user
    #dogs=Post.objects.all() #For seeing all entries 
    post= Post.objects.filter(created_by_user = user).order_by('-created_at')#[:4] #For seeing user specific entries
    #post_image=Post_image.post.all()
    print post_image
    context={'posts': post}
    return render(request, 'view.html', context)
else:
    messages.info(request, 'Session Expired')
    return redirect("/login")
```

models.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Post(models.Model):
   # user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=4500)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
   # user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True)
    created_by_user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
     )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title



class Post_image(models.Model):
    image=models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='post',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Where have you the biggest difficulties?

Comment: It's not clear what your actual question is.

Comment: I can't understand ` {% for image in posts.post.all %}`. How it is working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django uses the `related_name` of the foreign key to provide a reverse accessor - see the [related objects documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects). In your FK from Post_image to Post you have (strangely) called your foreign key "post", therefore you access the images via `post.post.all`.

Really you should give this a name that actually describe what it does: `images` would be more suitable. Although you could just as well remove the explicit related_name completely, in which case Django will use the default, which in this case would be `post_image_set`.

Comment: I removed related_name from db and using     `{% for image in post_image_set %}
   {{ image.image }}
   <a href='#'><img src='{{ image.image.url }}' class="img img-responsive image " width='100'/> </a><br>
   {% endfor %}` but I see blank div.

Comment: No, you still need to access it via the post, and you still need all. `{% for image in posts.post_image_set.all %}`

Comment: No, sir still the same results. Am I calling it right with     `{{image.image.url}}` ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It worked. what is     `post_image_set` doing?

Comment: I don't understand your question; isn't that explained in my answer?

Comment: Got it. went through the documentations and understood. Thanks.